# java while loop try catch, cant print to a new line

Tags: java

Having an issue here, I need this loop to print new lines of code to a file until but what it does is print 1 line then fails on the second time round,

Can never get it to print to another line, below is code

```
public class study  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
         BufferedWriter post =  null;
         File file = new File("text.txt");

            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            boolean promptUser = true;
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            post = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            try {
                while(promptUser){
                    System.out.println("enter age ");   //get age   
                    Scanner getage = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int age= getage.nextInt();

                    if(age <20 || age>50){ //age range
                        System.out.println("age must be between 20 and 50");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    System.out.println("enter name ");      //get name
                    Scanner getname = new Scanner(System.in);       
                    String name= getname.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("enter email "); //get email 
                    Scanner getarea = new Scanner(System.in);       
                    String email= getarea.nextLine();

                    post.write(age + "\t"); <===== fails here on second run
                    post.write(name + "\t");                    
                    post.write(email + "\t");
                    post.newLine();
                    post.close();

                    System.out.println("enter quit to quit or any key to continue");
                    Scanner options = new Scanner(System.in);   
                    String option = options.nextLine();     

                    if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){            
                            System.out.println("goodbye!");
                            System.exit(0);
                    } 
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why not you use bufferedWriter.newLine();after every entry while writing to the file i.e in your case post.newLine();

Comment: i do just before the close

Comment: why not you are trying after every post.write()

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it fails? If you get an Exception, please post the stack trace.

Comment: UPDATE, it no longer fails just keeps going until i say quit, which is fine. BUT its always printing the 1st line in the file over and over and not going to next line, there should be name email and age PER line, sorry for not clarifying

Answer (score 1):

```
            post.write(age + "\t"); 
            post.newLine();
            post.write(name + "\t");                    
            post.newLine();
            post.write(email + "\t");
            post.newLine();
```

//remove post.close(); from here
Now it may solve Your problem

Comment: my issue is that i need the program to loop and take data until i say quit, the thing the file only shows 1 line of data which is the last one entered, i need it to keep going next line of each SET of data

age,name,email (THEN NEXT LINE)
age,name,email

Comment: okay then you have to store the enterd value into set of arrays and then write or call any function which write these data exactly after  user enterd QUIT

Comment: im not good with arrays, could you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `post.close();` with `post.flush();` and you should be fine.

Close the stream when the exit condition is entered.

Comment: same thing, 1 line of data in file

Comment: @user3766275 I copy as it is and changed only the mentioned line and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT GUYS

I needed to move the FileWriter line out of the TRY

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class study {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter post =  null;

        File file = new File("text.txt"); //create file

        if (!file.exists())
        {
              file.createNewFile();
        }

        boolean promptUser = true;
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);

        try {
            while (promptUser) {
                post = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                System.out.println("enter age "); // get age    
                Scanner getage = new Scanner(System.in);        
                int age = getage.nextInt();

                if (age < 20 || age > 50){ //age range
                    System.out.println("age must be between 20 and 50");
                    System.exit(0);
                }   

                System.out.println("enter name "); //get name
                Scanner getname = new Scanner(System.in);       
                String name= getname.nextLine();

                System.out.println("enter email "); // get email    
                Scanner getarea = new Scanner(System.in);       
                String email= getarea.nextLine();

                //send data to file
                post.write(age + ";");
                post.write(name + ";");                 
                post.write(email + ";");
                post.newLine();
                post.flush();

                System.out.println("enter quit to quit or any key to continue");
                Scanner options = new Scanner(System.in);   
                String option = options.nextLine();     

                if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                    System.out.println("goodbye!");
                    post.close(); // close file upon quitting
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```